# What is the memory overhead of talloc allocations - from pools?

Tags: c, memory-management, pool

What is the memory overhead when using the [talloc](http://talloc.samba.org/talloc/doc/html/index.html) API instead of malloc and friends?

And what is the memory overhead when allocating from a [talloc pool](http://talloc.samba.org/talloc/doc/html/libtalloc__pools.html)?

Intuitively, one would think that the overhead for a normal talloc allocation is quite high because a header must contain a pointer to a parent/children, tags etc. But, on the other hand an allocation from a talloc pool is expected to have low memory overhead because pools are deallocated in a single operation (or in a stack-like fashion).

When allocating from a pool [the documentation](http://talloc.samba.org/talloc/doc/html/libtalloc__pools.html) specifies [no memory overhead](http://talloc.samba.org/talloc/doc/html/group__talloc.html#ga454194769421483dbd512f26c622f713) for those allocations.

Looking at the code of talloc.c, i.e.that [central line](http://gitweb.samba.org/?p=samba.git;a=blob;f=lib/talloc/talloc.c;h=1cb4d7dead792dad9bf362a1fb1025b3f802767d;hb=HEAD#l599)

```
tc = talloc_alloc_pool(ptc, TC_HDR_SIZE+size, prefix_len);
```

(and then tracing back to - say - [`__talloc()`](http://gitweb.samba.org/?p=samba.git;a=blob;f=lib/talloc/talloc.c;h=1cb4d7dead792dad9bf362a1fb1025b3f802767d;hb=HEAD#l651) which is called by e.g. `talloc_size()`)

it seems that the overhead for an allocation of size n is:

```
align16(n) + TC_HDR_SIZE = align16(n) + 96 // on x86-64
```

For a pool of size n and r allocations of size m from that pool the overhead is:

```
align16(n) + TC_HDR_SIZE > r * ( align16(n) + TC_HDR_SIZE )
```

This conflicts with the [examples of the documentation](http://talloc.samba.org/talloc/doc/html/libtalloc__pools.html).

For example a `uint64_t` allocation from a talloc pool uses **112 bytes** of pool memory.

Are my observations correct? Are the talloc pool examples wrong? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented [simplified talloc api](https://github.com/andrew-aladev/talloc2) with overhead **32-49 bytes** on 64 bit system. Overhead depends on features, that you want to use. talloc pool will be implemented in future release.

UPD

Pool is implemented in new 0.7 release

Answer (score 0):

I would say that talloc's metadata memory footprint is quite low since all it's storing in metadata are pointers and a main tree-like structure to hold the contexts, parents and child relationships.